# Finding dirty region by ps.rcPaint not works when style is WS_CHILD

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, gdi

I have written in C++ using WinApi procedure of painting. 
My callback function:

```
/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            {
                elWidget *widget = (elWidget *)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
                if (widget)
                {
                    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(widget->color.ColorRef());
                    FillRect((HDC)wParam, &ps.rcPaint, hBrush);
                    DeleteObject(hBrush);
                    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine for standalone windows (where style is `WS_OVERLAPPED`), but when style is `WS_CHILD` or `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE` then always `ps.rcPaint` is (0,0,0,0). I don't know how fix it.

```
elButton::elButton(elWidget *owner)
        : elWidget(owner)
{
    WNDCLASSEX winclChild;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */
    /* The Window structure */
    winclChild.hInstance = gThisInstance; //global variable instance
    winclChild.lpszClassName = L"Child";
    winclChild.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    winclChild.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    winclChild.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    winclChild.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    winclChild.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    winclChild.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    winclChild.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    winclChild.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    winclChild.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    winclChild.hbrBackground = 0;// CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 200, 200));//(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;//COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&winclChild))
        return;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
        L"Child",         /* Classname */
        L"Title",       /* Title Text */
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        100,
        100,
        40,
        40,
        owner->getHwnd(),        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
        NULL,                /* No menu */
        gThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
        this                 /* to lParam */
       );
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (long)this);
}
```

I can add link to whole project on Google Disk, but I cannot guarantee it will be permanent for years.

Comment: A random guess is that you forgot to set the CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW class style flags.  You'll need to show the code that calls RegisterWindow/Ex() and CreateWindow/Ex().

Comment: WNDCLASSEX winclChild;      
  winclChild.style = CS_DBLCLKS 
  if (!RegisterClassEx(&winclChild))
  return;
 hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to show a [mcve] so that we don't have to extract the code from you in this way?

Comment: First answer: but both window are red; if we apply "unsigned style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE); if ((style & WS_CHILD) != 0) FillRect((HDC)wParam, &ps.rcPaint, hBrush);" both will be white else red

Comment: @Saku: I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Mykola: this answer works perfectly for me too. Thanks, each class must have own procedure?

Comment: No you can do this with one procedure. Tested for me.

Comment: You must create different classes else it not works.

Comment: The bug is in your SetWindowLong() call, it is too late.  Google "wm_nccreate setwindowlongptr" to find the proper way to do this.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

BeginPaint should be called only on WM_PAINT,

to get the clipping box on WM_ERASEBKGND call `GetClipBox((HDC)wParam,&rect);` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` for `WM_PAINT` only.

From Windows documentation for [**`WM_PAINT`**:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> An application should not call **`BeginPaint`** except in response to
>   a **`WM_PAINT`** message. Each call to `BeginPaint` must have a
>   corresponding call to the `EndPaint` function.

While your code may appear to work, it is likely causing problems elsewhere, for example in `WM_PAINT`

To get the update region from outside `WM_PAINT`, use `GetUpdateRect`. However, `GetUpdateRect` cannot be used in `WM_ERASEBKGND`. See also [**`GetUpdateRect`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

A simple solution is forcing `WM_ERASEBKGND` to do nothing, then handle everything in `WM_PAINT`

```
switch(msg)
{
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    return TRUE;
case WM_PAINT:
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, but I prefer economically redraw only dirty parts;

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly for me. The answer is we must define separate windows classes for parent and child window respectively. I saw that `SetWindowLong` works properly in all cases. But if you whant to redraw new window immediately with new data you must remove `WS_VISIBLE` as your creation style, and to  `SetWindowLong` before `ShowWindow`. `ShowWindow` function make your window visible and redraw it with the new parameters.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,
                         UINT message,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam);

int RegClass(HINSTANCE hInstance,LPCTSTR lpszClassName)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCTSTR)lpszClassName;
    wc.lpszMenuName = (LPCTSTR)NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_CROSS);
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}

HWND hWnd0, hWnd1;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nShowCmd)
{
    MSG message;

    static LPCTSTR lpszClName = L"Wnd Class";
    static LPCTSTR lpszCl0Name = L"Child Class";
    if(!RegClass(hInstance,lpszClName))
        exit(0);
    if(!RegClass(hInstance,lpszCl0Name))
        exit(0);

    hWnd0 = CreateWindow(
        lpszClName,
        L"Привіт!",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800,
        600,
        0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    hWnd1 = CreateWindow(
        lpszCl0Name,
        L"Привіт!",
        WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        40,
        40,
        400,
        300,
        hWnd0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    ShowWindow(hWnd0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd0);

    RECT WndRect;

    // For parent redraw
    GetWindowRect(hWnd0, &WndRect);
    MoveWindow(hWnd0, WndRect.left, WndRect.top, 801, 601, TRUE);

    SetWindowLong(hWnd0, GWL_USERDATA, RGB(0, 255, 0));

    ShowWindow(hWnd1,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd1);

    while (GetMessage(&message,0,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    return message.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,
                         UINT message,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            {
                if (true)
                {
                    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

                    COLORREF color = (hWnd == hWnd0) ? RGB(255, 0, 0) : GetWindowLong(hWnd0, GWL_USERDATA);

                    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(color);
                    FillRect((HDC)wParam, &ps.rcPaint, hBrush);
                    DeleteObject(hBrush);
                    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

                    ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result will be.

[image]

Comment: But stay one problem: windows for classes can have separate colors, but no way to relate window with object which has color. Before CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx value of hWnd is unknown. After CreateWindow already is called WndProc, especially for WS_CHILD. No BeginUpdate is bad but erase background is run at once, before setting SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (long)this) or put to Map<hwnd, object>. This is problem.

Comment: @Saku: It not so clear what you writing about, I simply cannot understand the problem. Could you try to write more cleary what you ty to achive? Posible by steps?

Comment: @Saku: Did you try to tell me that there is no way to send messages to windows wich are not created?

Comment: Solution: should not be WS_VISIBLE style because WndProc run before SetWindowLong